# Логирование и многопоточность

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность, логирование

Я делаю многопоточный сервер на стандартном модуле threading. Каждый поток этого сервера считывает из очереди задачи и запускает класс обработчик, который выглядит примерно так:

```
class Worker:
    def __init__(self, parameters):
        ***********
        log_name = 'name.log'  # тут задается имя лога в зависимости от обработчика
        logging.basicConfig(format=u'%(filename)s[LINE:%(lineno)d]# %(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s]  %(message)s', filename=log_name, level=log_level)
        ***********

    def start_operation(self):
        ***********
        logging.info(u'сообщение')
        ***********
```

И лог ведется... Но только один. не на каждый поток отдельный, а один общий для всех. Причем имя файла для лога задается тем потоком, который первый запустился и выполнил строчку logging.basicConfig.

Очевидно, что я что-то не понимаю в работе модуля logging. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Если вы хотите отдельный лог на каждый поток, у вас два варианта - создавать отдельный файл лога, либо в самих сообщениях ставить метку потока, оставившего сообщение. Потоки можно различать по thread specific переменной, ею может быть что угодно - от TID до специальной информации (в случае WEB например это может быть адрес клиента или номер задачи в обработке). Вариант с кучей файликов не очень удобен, так анализировать потом эти логи будет крайне трудно - их будет столько, сколько потоков вы запустите

Comment: Логика работы такова, что для каждого экземпляра обработчика необходим отдельный лог-файл. Я не понимаю почему строка:`logging.basicConfig(format=u'%(filename)s[LINE:%(lineno)d]# %(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s]  %(message)s', filename=log_name, level=log_level)` не содает отдельный фал для лога.

Comment: если уж делаете многопоточный сервер, то стоит открыть справку по logging и увидеть ответ как правильно создать logger на первой-же стринице https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мою проблему решил следующий подход:

```
class Worker:
    def __init__(self, parameters):
        file_to_log = 'адрес файла каталога'
        handler = logging.FileHandler(file_to_log, 'a')
        handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)      # или другой нужный уровень логирования
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(filename)s[LINE:%(lineno)d]# %(levelname)-3s [%(asctime)s] %(message)s',
                                  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)       # или другой нужный уровень логирования
        logger.addHandler(handler)


    def start_operation(self):
        logger.debug(u'сообщение')
        logger.info(u'сообщение')
```